# pig - how to use python udf to calculate velocity from dataset

Tags: jython, apache-pig

I haven't found too many tutorials on using udfs with bags.

Let's say I have a following dataset:

```
UID : distance_from_something : timestamp
100:100:0
100:101:1
100:102:2
200:200:0
200:202:3
200:204:6
300:300:0
300:303:5
```

Now I would like to calculate velocity for each UID

```
data = LOAD 'testfile' USING PigStorage(':') AS (
    uid:long,
    distance:int,
    time_raw:long);

SPLIT data INTO
    good_data IF (
        (uid > 0L)),
    bad_data OTHERWISE;

REGISTER '$UDFPATH//calculateVelocity.py' USING jython AS vcalc;

grouped_data = GROUP good_data BY (long)$0;
data = FOREACH grouped_data GENERATE vcalc.calculate(good_data);
flat_data = FOREACH data GENERATE FLATTEN($0);
```

Is this a good way to do this sort of thing, if for example I wanted output to look something like:

```
100:100:0:1
100:101:1:1
100:102:2:1
200:200:0:0.666...
200:202:3:0.666...
200:204:6:0.666...
300:300:0:0.6
300:303:5:0.6
```

And what would be the best way in this sort of scenario to calculate velocity using non-linear interpolation?

This is my current placeholder:

```
def compared_to_previous(bag, index):
    dx = float(bag[index][1] - bag[index - 1][1])
    dt = float(bag[index][-1] - bag[index - 1][-1])/1000
    return dx/dt

def compared_to_next(bag, index):
    return compared_to_previous(bag, index+1)

def calculate(inBag):
    outBag = []

    index = 0
    tuples = len(inBag)
    for t in inBag:
        row = list(t)
        if not index:
            row.append(compared_to_next(inBag, index))
        elif index == tuples - 1:
            row.append(compared_to_previous(inBag, index))
        else:
            v = compared_to_previous(inBag, index)
            v += compared_to_next(inBag, index)
            row.append(v/2)
        outBag.append(tuple(row))

    return outBag
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll leave it up to you to actually implement the calculation of velocity -- it's not clear how you will handle variable speed, for one, and that implementation is not a Pig question.  But getting this data into a UDF is pretty easy.

You don't want to pass `good_data` to the UDF -- that refers to a relation, not a field.  You need to collect together all the records for each UID and then pass that collection to a UDF that knows how to handle them:

```
data =
    FOREACH (GROUP good_data BY uid)
    GENERATE
        group,
        FLATTEN(vcalc.calculate(good_data.(distance, time_raw)));
```

The input to your UDF is a bag of pairs of the form (distance, time_raw), and your output should be a bag of triples of the form (distance, time_raw, velocity).

Comment: how does your implementation differ from one I have added to original question? Is there any practical differences?

Comment: It looks like you implemented basically what I suggested.  The only cosmetic difference is that you kept the UID throughout the UDF whereas I `GENERATE`d it immediately, but that's of no importance.